Using VSTACK to pile-up results
I'm trying to solve what should be a simple problem.
In the picture below I show what I'm trying to do, and what it doesn't work.
I think that the range "expected result" speaks for itself.
Solving the problem for one single row (A) works perfectly.
Solving the problem for one single row with the BYROW function (B) doesn't work, and I cannot understand why it doesn't.
Solving the problem for several rows (C) has been a nightmare for me, and still I do not know how to get the desired result.
I think that the formula for case (C) should imply LAMBDA, VSTACK and LET functions, but I cannot get it.
Can anybody give me a hint?
I'm looking for a solution with dynamic arrays.


To select column please try INDEX(r;;2).

Repeat Array Vertically (TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE...)
Repeat Column

Based on Mayukh Bhattacharya's answer to "How to convert a column of age counts into a set useful for statistics?":

=LET(data,A2:A4,repeats,B2:B4,
    TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(,MAX(repeats))<=repeats,data),2))


Repeat Transposed Row

Based on JvdV's answer to "Repeat values excel":

=LET(data,B1:D1,repeats,B2:D2,
    TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(MAX(repeats))<=repeats,data),2,1))


Both + Optional HSTACK (LAMBDA Function)

Use the following in the Name Manager to create a LAMBDA function, e.g. RepeatArray:

=LAMBDA(data,repeats,[h_stack],LET(
    h,IF(ISOMITTED(h_stack),0,h_stack),
    a,ROWS(data)=1,
    m,MAX(repeats),
    s,IFS(SEQUENCE(IF(a,m,1),IF(a,1,m))<=repeats,data),
    IF(h,TOROW(s,2,a),TOCOL(s,2,a))))


Anywhere in your workbook, you can now use =RepeatArray(A2:A4,B2:B4) to stack the data vertically, or =RepeatArray(A2:A4,B2:B4,1) to stack the data horizontally. The same goes for vertical inputs.


=LET(n,B6:B8,
     c,C6:C8,
TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(n),MAX(n),LAMBDA(x,y,IFS(INDEX(c,x)>=y,INDEX(n,x)))),2))

It loops through the numbers in n and repeats it if the column number of the array created by MAKEARRAY (sized the maximum number in range b).
If the column number of the current row is greater than the n-number of current row, it errors, else it returns the current row's n.
TOCOL flattens the array, removing the errors.
Alternately (added in binary search thanks to VBasics explanation on performance): =XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(C6:C8)),SCAN(,C6:C8,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),B6:B8,,1,2)
Or if you intend on using VSTACK:
=LET(n,B6:B8,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(n)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(C6:C8,y)),INDEX(n,y))))),1))

This is simple and perfect!

The performance of these formulas applied on a large dataset is horrible. They took 2s: MAKEARRAY for only 300, REDUCE for 2500, and XLOOKUP for 3000 records (stacks). The data was =RANDARRAY(100000,,1000,9999,1) while the repeats were =RANDARRAY(100000,,1,20,1) both copied as values. You can't do anything about REDUCE, it is slow. MAKEARRAY, the worst, comes as a total surprise (to me). Finally, you can 'save' XLOOKUP by setting the 6th parameter to 2 (binary ASC) when it performs the same as TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE...: 100k records (+1M resulting rows) in less than a second.

@VBasic2008 I know about REDUCE VSTACK being a slow combi, but I added it since it was referred to in the question. I expected makearray not to be slow. I'm also interested how the suggested XLOOKUP performed compared to your suggested solutions.

About DROP(REDUCE/VSTACK: Once you figure out how to use it, you'll be able 'to do anything'. You'll start stacking around like a lunatic. Once you encounter a large enough dataset, not so much anymore. Then you'll want to figure out more efficient solutions. Nevertheless, IMO it is the ultimate Excel function. Imagine you have to solve something immediately, and you don't feel up to figuring out the 'deep math' behind it. Then you'll simply use DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(10),LAMBDA(rr,r,VSTACK(rr,r))),1) and replace the 10 and r with whatever you need and have the result in minutes...

... It's like VLOOKUP ('everybody' knows how to use it) with the key difference that 'it can do anything' (not 'everybody' knows how to use it, yet). IMO, any solution using it is valid (you don't see me down-voting). BTW, I meant "you know it is slow" but I didn't have enough characters.

About XLOOKUP/SCAN: By simply appending ,2 after the 1 you'll make your slow formula perform at the same 'lightning speed' as my TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(. I was shocked when I realized it was so fast so I'll have to study it in depth. About MAKEARRAY: I expected it to be at least twice as slow as my formula but was disappointed when it turned out to be much slower than the REDUCE. Sometimes shifting the functions around makes a huge difference. Not sure if this applies here. At the moment, I don't know exactly how it works but I'll have to study it, too.

One more way to EXPAND:)
=LAMBDA(data,
    REDUCE(
        "Result",
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
            LET(
                val, INDEX(data, cur, 1),
                times, INDEX(data, cur, 2),
                VSTACK(acc, EXPAND(val, times, , val))
            )
        )
    )
)(A2:B4)


Also, since you seem to like using LAMBDA etc., you may want to look at Excel Labs | Microsoft Garage, if you haven't already.
